Copy & paste between MacOs and Windows
Is there any clean and simple solution that allows copying and pasting text and images between a Windows device and a MacOs one?
I'm considering buying either an iPad Pro or a Samsung Galaxy Book 4 360 to work alongside my current Mac Studio. I really appreciate the ability to copy on my Mac and paste on an iPad, but the 16'' screen of the Samsung catches my attention. That's why I'm asking if with a Samsung laptop, there is any software that allows me to copy and paste between this device and the Mac in an easy and simple way, ideally, just like between an iPad and a Mac.
I found a related question here (Is there a way to copy and paste text and images between two computers?), but was posed > 13 years ago.

@John - That would appear to work for file transfer, but not clipboard.

VNC is still around.

There are 3rd party utilities that appear to offer this soft of thing. What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this?

The linked question's solution is still viable. It is a true duplicate.
